# XSLT with nodeset as external parameter

Tags: java, xslt

I'm passing XML nodes to my JAVA transformer:

```
transformer.setParameter("orset", qRes);
```

The contents of qRes is similar to this:

```
<DOCTYPES>
    <SUBTYPE>Passport</SUBTYPE>
    <DOCTYPE>Proof of identity</DOCTYPE>
</DOCTYPES>
<DOCTYPES>
    <SUBTYPE>Driving License</SUBTYPE>
    <DOCTYPE>Proof of address</DOCTYPE>
</DOCTYPES>
```

I have a global parameter declared in my XSL file:

```
<xsl:param name="orset"/>
```

Can I access specific values from the parameter something like this:

```
<xsl:for-each SELECT="$orset/DOCTYPES">
<xsl:value-of select="$orset/DOCTYPES/DOCTYPE"/>
...
```

Or what would be the proper way of doing this?

Many thanks!

Comment: It's ok to pass any XPath/Infoset/XDM instance as paramerter to an XSLT stylesheet as long as the XSLT processor provides a proper API.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are best to use the eXslt node-set function...

```
<xsl:stylesheet xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"
  xmlns:exsl="http://exslt.org/common"
  extension-element-prefixes="exsl"
  version="1.0">
 ...
 <xsl:value-of select="exsl:node-set($orset)/DOCTYPES"/>
  ...
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

There are alternative node-set functions available based on your processor etc, they are all listed in the below reference.

http://www.xml.com/pub/a/2003/07/16/nodeset.html

Comment: I'm doing some testing within the xls file and I had to change the stylesheet version to 2.0 in order to be able to use node-sets.

Comment: "You might be wondering whether the node-set() function will be part of these standards. The answer is no, but don't worry. The authors of XSLT 2.0 made an important decision: result tree fragments are gone. There will be no need to use the node-set() function in XSLT 2.0 as you can operate directly on XML fragments stored in a variable, as on any other node-set. Regardless, you should put the node-set() function in your bag of tools as it will take several years before XSLT 2.0 will be deployed as widely as XSLT 1.0 is deployed today." http://www.xml.com/pub/a/2003/07/16/nodeset.html#d0e247

Comment: I read that bit. I'm now using node-set but still had to change the version of the stylesheet to 2.0. It is working now but I'm not sure what the impact is.